# Swagger-codegen renames methods with same names

Tags: java, swagger-codegen, api-doc

I have generate a swagger client api with:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-2.2.3/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://localhost:8080/myproject/services/service0/swagger.json -l java -o client/myproject/java
```

But swagger-codegen rename methods with same names **despite the fact that they are in different java clases**. Is there any option to solve that issue?

Comment: how about using fully qualified class names in mustache template?

Comment: Please open a ticket via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the swagger codegen community can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The renaming of method will not affect the URL path and you should be able to make the REST call with the generated UI .

Even i don't know the reason why Swagger code gen works that way .

But i also feel that our API consumers doesn't have to know the method which are called  either . So generated UI should be good to go